# what is the autoplay button while in battle?

Tags: angry-birds-epic

While in battle mode there is a like "play" button in bottom right corner, if you click it the birds will fight in "auto-pilot" mode.

What is the point in having the button? I mean, you can click it and just wait for the battle to finish.

upd:
What the button actually do? Is this really an auto-pilot feature?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it's asking why a developer did what they did.

Comment: @Rapitor I'm asking what the button actually do. Not sure if it's really an auto-pilot, maybe it's has some side effects to the game. Sorry, it's isn't from the question, will update

Comment: Alright, that made it more clear. Retracted my vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoplay isn't totally dumb, it'll buff your birds when they're unbuffed or heal injured birds but it's also not totally smart. It can attempt to heal when all birds are at full health too. **It will use your primary, secondary and even rage chili skills when available.**

I suspect it exists to make grinding for basic components easier. You can just find that one fight that has a 3x reward for, say, coral and autofight it over and over again - assuming you're a high enough level to be reasonably successful with autoplay.

Comment: +1 for grinding! I was getting annoyed with doing that just today and never considered autoplay!